# ActiveJob - Processing a large number of ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activejob

I'm writing a background job to process a large number of users and create a `UserFlag` for each one. I have 18,000 users to process. I currently have the user ids and I've written the job as so:

```
class BatchProcessUsersJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform()
    user_ids = [
      # 18,000 ids
    ]

    UserFlag.add_flag_to_users(user_ids, UserFlag::PRODUCT_TYPE_2)
  end
end
```

on the UserFlag

```
  def self.add_flag_to_users(user_ids, flag)
    users_with_flag = UserFlag.where(user_id: user_ids).where(flag: flag).pluck(:user_id)
    users_without_flags = user_ids - users_with_flag
    return if users_without_flags.empty?

    users_without_flags.uniq.each do |user_id|
      UserFlag.find_or_create_by(user_id: user_id, flag: flag)
    end
  end
```

My question is whether or not the job can handle 18,000 users in this way. This doesn't seem safe and seems like it would be susceptible to timing out or.. something else. Additionally, it feels very messy to be processing that many users in this way; it feel bad. Is there a different way I should be approaching this?

Comment: This isn't going to be unsafe but it's going to be slow as hell and eat up a lot of memory.   In order to actually give you a meaningful answer we are going to need to see your models. The solution is most likely to just use `.upsert_all` to to add the missing records in a single database query.  https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-upsert_all

Comment: Knowing which database you're using would also help.

Answer (score 0):

You can split your 18k ids array in multiple groups and pass on to the `add_flag_to_users` method for batch processing of these groups.

For splitting of the `user_ids` array you can either use ruby specific [each_slice](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) method or rails specific [in_groups_of](https://apidock.com/rails/Array/in_groups_of) method.

For example, using each_slice method your above code will look something like below which is splitting the array to groups of 500 ids:

```
class BatchProcessUsersJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform()
    user_ids = [
      # 18,000 ids
    ]
    user_ids.each_slice(500) do |group|
      UserFlag.add_flag_to_users(group, UserFlag::PRODUCT_TYPE_2)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I use similar trick in my Job to update multiple attributes in 30k+ records after every 1 hour periodically and it works like a charm.